# mvn jax2b not generating java classes from wsdl

Tags: java, spring, maven, wsdl

In my spring project, following [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/#initial) tutorial I have the following in my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>soapTest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.13.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                        <generatePackage>com.example</generatePackage>
                        <schemas>
                            <schema>
                                <url>http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl</url>
                            </schema>
                        </schemas>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

according to the tutorial java class generation is part of the project build but still I can't see any java classes generated for my project.

I've tried `mvn package` and `mvn clean compile` but not luck there. Any idea what am I missing here?

**EDIT 1:** here is the exception output for when I put the plugin outside the pluginManagement

```
Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/core/TypeInfoSet
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1-1903499108
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core-0.13.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.2.1/commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/20050927/resolver-20050927.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb22-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb22-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.2.11/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.4/maven-plugin-annotations-3.4.jar
Number of foreign imports: 5
import: Entry[import org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.Scanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.AbstractScanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------
 (org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate:default:generate-sources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/core/TypeInfoSet
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1-1903499108
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core-0.13.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.2.1/commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/20050927/resolver-20050927.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb22-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb22-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.2.11/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.4/maven-plugin-annotations-3.4.jar
Number of foreign imports: 5
import: Entry[import org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.Scanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.AbstractScanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/core/TypeInfoSet
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1-1903499108
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core-0.13.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.2.1/commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/20050927/resolver-20050927.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb22-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb22-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.2.11/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/arash.jahromi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.4/maven-plugin-annotations-3.4.jar
Number of foreign imports: 5
import: Entry[import org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.Scanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.AbstractScanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:166)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/core/TypeInfoSet
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:688)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:380)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:164)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:613)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:569)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:555)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:884)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.core.TypeInfoSet
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 82 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The maven `pluginManagement` only tells maven, which plugin it should use, when it is called in any pom inside of the plugins section. `pluginManagement` will never executed directly. So you have to put your code outside of pluginManagement` and fix the exception.

From the [Maven-POM-reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html):

> pluginManagement: is an element that is seen along side plugins.
>   Plugin Management contains plugin elements in much the same way,
>   except that rather than configuring plugin information for this
>   particular project build, it is intended to configure project builds
>   that inherit from this one. However, this only configures plugins that
>   are actually referenced within the plugins element in the children.
>   The children have every right to override pluginManagement
>   definitions.

If you post it here, we can try to help you.

**UPDATE:**
You get the exception, because a dependency is missing `class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/core/TypeInfoSet`.
Add

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-osgi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-osgi</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

To your pom.xml and it should work.

Comment: but if I follow the tutorial and put my plugin outside of the `pluginManagement` it will throw and exception. I will update the question with the exception

Comment: updated the question with the maven exception output

Comment: do I have to run any mvn command to update it? Because I just added the dependency but the same error was thrown again

Comment: @arashmoeen Where you have added the dependency

Comment: @arashmoeen Have changed my answer. The class has moved to an other jar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123206/discussion-between-arash-moeen-and-jens).